# Specify lookup_url_kwarg in the nested route using drf-nested-routers

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, drf-nested-routers

Using [`drf-nested-routers`](https://github.com/alanjds/drf-nested-routers) we have implemented many nested routes that go two levels in depth.

Just as in the [documented examples](https://github.com/alanjds/drf-nested-routers#infinite-depth-nesting):

```
/clients/
/clients/{pk}/
/clients/{client_pk}/maildrops/
/clients/{client_pk}/maildrops/{pk}/
/clients/{client_pk}/maildrops/{maildrop_pk}/recipients/
/clients/{client_pk}/maildrops/{maildrop_pk}/recipients/{pk}/
```

However, I don't like the inconsistency in the 4th line. How can I make the `lookup_url_kwarg` be `maildrop_pk` there too?

```
/clients/{client_pk}/maildrops/{maildrop_pk}/
```

This is how the `urls.py` looks like:

```py
# urls.py
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'clients', ClientViewSet, basename='clients')
## generates:
# /clients/
# /clients/{pk}/

client_router = routers.NestedSimpleRouter(router, r'clients', lookup='client')
client_router.register(r'maildrops', MailDropViewSet, basename='maildrops')
## generates:
# /clients/{client_pk}/maildrops/
# /clients/{client_pk}/maildrops/{pk}/

maildrops_router = routers.NestedSimpleRouter(client_router, r'maildrops', lookup='maildrop')
maildrops_router.register(r'recipients', MailRecipientViewSet, basename='recipients')
## generates:
# /clients/{client_pk}/maildrops/{maildrop_pk}/recipients/
# /clients/{client_pk}/maildrops/{maildrop_pk}/recipients/{pk}/

urlpatterns = [
    path(r'', include(router.urls)),
    path(r'', include(client_router.urls)),
    path(r'', include(maildrops_router.urls)),
]
```

If I set the `lookup_url_kwarg` in the `MailDropViewSet` to `maildrop_pk`:

```py
class MailDropViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    serializer_class = MailDropSerializer
    lookup_url_kwarg = "maildrop_pk"
```

then the routes look like this:

```
/clients/{client_pk}/maildrops/{maildrop_pk}/
/clients/{client_pk}/maildrops/{maildrop_maildrop_pk}/recipients/
/clients/{client_pk}/maildrops/{maildrop_maildrop_pk}/recipients/{pk}/
```

I want to have a consistent naming of the URL lookup kwargs across the routes, like:

```
/clients/{client_pk}/maildrops/{maildrop_pk}/
/clients/{client_pk}/maildrops/{maildrop_pk}/recipients/
/clients/{client_pk}/maildrops/{maildrop_pk}/recipients/{pk}/
```

but I can't see how this can be configured.

Comment: Can you share how you use the router?

Comment: I'm using the example from the official documentation, linked above in the question.

Comment: What if you remove `, lookup='client'`, so `routers.NestedSimpleRouter(router, r'clients')`, and thus still work with `client_pk` in the `lookup_url_kwarg`?

Comment: There's this line in the source code: `self.nest_prefix = kwargs.pop('lookup', 'nested_%i' % self.nest_count) + '_'`. If I don't pass a value for `lookup` it will be generated as `nested_1_pk` or `nested_1_maildrop_pk`, depending on `lookup_url_kwarg` in the viewset. If I pass an empty `lookup` value, then it will be generated as `_pk` or `_maildrop_pk`.

Comment: sorry: `routers.NestedSimpleRouter(router, r'clients', lookup='')`

Comment: As explained in my comment, that still adds the underscore (`_`) as prefix :(

Answer (score 1):

Although not ideal, an idea might be to make our own `NestedSimpleRouter`, with:

```
from rest_framework_nested.routers import NestedMixin


class OurNestedMixin(NestedMixin):
    def __init__(self, parent_router, parent_prefix, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.nest_prefix = kwargs.get('lookup', 'nested_%i' % self.nest_count)
```

and mix this into a `NestedSimpleRouter`:

```
from rest_framework_nested.routers import NestedMixin


class OurNestedSimpleRouter(OurNestedMixin, NestedSimpleRouter):
    pass
```

then we thus can use this as:

```
# urls.py
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'clients', ClientViewSet, basename='clients')

client_router = OurNestedSimpleRouter(router, r'clients', lookup='')
client_router.register(r'maildrops', MailDropViewSet, basename='maildrops')

maildrops_router = OurNestedSimpleRouter(client_router, r'maildrops', lookup='')
maildrops_router.register(
    r'recipients', MailRecipientViewSet, basename='recipients'
)
```

so then the `lookup_url_kwarg`s of the `ViewSet`s determine the names of the parameters, and this will then define the URL patterns.

The consequence is of course that the `lookup_url_kwarg` should be defined on all `ViewSet`s in such way that for all paths they generate, there are never two path parameters with the same name.

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking to do some monkey patching, but wasn't sure about the approach. However, I'm not sure what you mean by "mix this into a `NestedSimpleSerializer`".

Comment: @cezar: the `OurNestedMixin` is a mixin, so we create a class `OurNestedSimpleRouter` where we mix it into that class, which will thus override the `__init__` (through the mixin).

Comment: I think the `Serializer` part is a typo.